# How do I resolve img src not being recognized?

Tags: html, typescript, webpack, tailwind-css

Using TypeScript to prepend a header across several html pages and I'm having trouble getting it to recognize and img src.
The image doesnt load and if I try to open the image I get an error stating "Cannot GET /src/main/resource/img/logo.png"
[website screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Fn5C.png)

Here's my code:

```
    const logoImage: HTMLImageElement = document.createElement('img');
        logoImage.classList.add('h-10', 'w-10', 'inline-block');
        logoImage.src = "./resource/img/logo.png"
```

Snippet of relevant directories look like this:

```
|--|--html
|--|--|--index.html
|--|--resource\img
|--|--|--logo.png
|--|--ts
|--|--|--index.ts
|--|--|--navbar.ts
```

Tech Used:

- HTML
- Node
- Webpack
- Tailwind/SCSS/SASS
- Typescript

I've also tried `src/main/resource/img/logo.png` and `../resource/img/logo.png` in place of it but it doesn't seem to like it either. TypeScript also isn't taking `'\'` as an acceptable separator either. I expected these to work but nothing changes.

Comment: Use the dev tool (F12). Then either look into the dev console or into the network tab and see if the image getting loaded there or what error message the image throws. It might be that the const already throws an error.

Comment: Relative URLs are relative to the file itself.  You would need `"../resource/img/logo.png"`.

Comment: To confirm the possible inconsistency of your diagram of the directory structure, the "logo.png" file is in the "img" subdirectory of the "resource" directory? Additionally, confirm that the "resource" directory is not spelled plural "resources"

Comment: your image url is not working You need just drop and drag your image to your code it will create it path automatically

Comment: you need try a bundle tool, like `vite` `webpack` `rollup`

Answer (score 0):

when using webpack:

```js
import logoImageFile from "./resource/img/logo.png";
// -OR-
const logoImageFile = require("./resource/img/logo.png");

const logoImage: HTMLImageElement = document.createElement('img');
logoImage.classList.add('h-10', 'w-10', 'inline-block');
logoImage.src = logoImageFile;
```

Using `import` or `require`, webpack resolves the source image file and processes it via the `asset/resource` module.

The `logoImageFile` is resolved and processed output filename in `dist/` directory.